# PHP / Mysql handle query errors

Tags: php, mysqli

How to handle errors in mysql queries. Suppose I have 2 insert queries (two different tables), first one executes successfully and if second one fails for some reason then how do I undo the insert/update that happened in my first one? Please provide some suggestions as Im beginner in php.

Comment: It's called a `transaction`. Google might give you some tutorials about this

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html